# Could not increase accuracy from a fixed threshold using Keras Dense layer ANN

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm learning the simplest neural networks using Dense layers using Keras. I'm trying to implement face recognition on a relatively small dataset (In total ~250 images with 50 images per class).

I've downloaded the images from google images and resized them to 100 * 100 `png` files. Then I've read those files into a `numpy` array and also created a one hot label array for training my model.

Here is my code for processing the training data:

```
X, Y = [], []
feature_map = {
    'Alia Bhatt': 0,
    'Dipika Padukon': 1,
    'Shahrukh khan': 2,
    'amitabh bachchan': 3,
    'ayushmann khurrana': 4
}
for each_dir in os.listdir('.'):
  if os.path.isdir(each_dir):
    for each_file in os.listdir(each_dir):
      X.append(cv2.imread(os.path.join(each_dir, each_file), -1).reshape(1, -1))
      Y.append(feature_map[os.path.basename(each_file).split('-')[0]])

X = np.squeeze(X)
X = X / 255.0 # normalize the training data
Y = np.array(Y)
Y = np.eye(5)[Y]
print (X.shape)
print (Y.shape)
```

This is printing `(244, 40000)` and `(244, 5)`. Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(8000, input_dim = 40000, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1200, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(700, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=25, batch_size=15)
```

When I train the model, It stuck at the accuracy `0.2172`, which is almost the same as random predictions (0.20).

I've also tried to train mode with grayscale images but still not getting expected accuracy. Also tried with different network architectures by changing the number of hidden layers and neurons in hidden layers.

What am I missing here? Is my dataset too small? or am I missing any other technical detail?

For more details of code, here is my notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1hSVirKYO5NFH3VWtXfr1h6y0sxHjI5Ey

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions I can make:

1. Your data set is probably too small. If you are splitting training and validation at 80/20, that means you are only training on 200 images, which is probably too small. Try increasing your data set to see if results improve.
2. I would recommend adding Dropout to each layer of your network as your training set is so small. Your network is most likely over-fitting your training data set since it is so small, and Dropout is an easy way to help avoid this problem.

Let me know if these suggestions make a difference!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the dataset is too small, 50 instances of each person is probably not enough. You can use data augmentation with the keras [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) method to increase the number of images, and rewrite your numpy reshaping code as a pre-processing function for the generator. I also noticed that you haven't shuffled the data, so the network is likely predicting the first class for everything (which is maybe why the accuracy is near random chance).

If increasing the dataset size doesn't help, you'll probably have to play around with the learning rate for the Adam optimizer.